# schtasks command not executing after adding /RU SYSTEM

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

Scheduling a task like this results in success, and also works as intended:

```
schtasks.exe /CREATE /TN MsUpdater /TR target path... /SC ONLOGON /RL HIGHEST
```

However, I would like to change its behaviour. I would like it to start on any logon, and not just when the user that scheduled the task is currently logged in.

To achieve that I found the `/NP` and `/RU SYSTEM` arguments.

`/NP` is not what I want, as it limits my application to local resources. And after adding `/RU SYSTEM` to my command, the schedule is broken - the application never starts.

I would like to know why adding `/RU SYSTEM` breaks my command, and how to fix this behaviour, or how to alternatively schedule a task on any logon.

Comment: How does it break? Do you get an error message? Does the task start but fail?

Comment: It says "running" in task scheduler but the file is never actually executed. No errors, no logs or traces of anything. Tested on 3 desktops, all of which are Windows 10

Comment: And readding the task without /RU SYSTEM fixes the issue

Comment: Is your command prompt elevated? (did you start it as admin?)

Comment: Yes, obviously, otherwise I wouldn't be able to add the task.

Comment: So I check, the RU is just the user used to run the script, so using the system user or not should not change anything as long as the user has the rights to the script.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm thinking, but it just doesn't work

Comment: I also recreated your script on my machine without the RU and when I run it is does in fact create the task for all users logging into my machine. Is it possible that the other users your are using do not have access to that script?

Comment: No way! Yes, it creates a task for all users but it executes as long as the creator of the task is logged in.

Comment: Oh guess not sorry. Not sure what I did first time around, but didn't work this time.

Comment: So my last suggestion would be to use a GPO instead to run the script, since I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: Could you please explain how to create a GPO from command line that would fit my needs? Never worked with GPO before

Comment: You can't create it from the command line. You'd usually have an active directory or setup a local GP using `gpedit.msc`. What's the last run result for the task in the task scheduler? What kind of program are you trying to run?

Comment: It's an updater, a part of my C# application. Says application executed successfully and the task state stopped at "Running". But my app works OK and /RU SYSTEM is broken for me even on system apps like calc.exe